# How do backend and frontend developer work together on same project from different location

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api

I and a friend want to work on same project but we are in different location.

I will be working on backend while he will be working on frontend.

How do I feed him with my backend API. What's the best solution, app or tools to use.

Answer (score 1):

Strongly recommend using git as a collaboration/version control tool. You can sign up for free at github.com and they now support private repositories. There's a bit of a learning curve, but git is highly adopted and one of the standards for managing code between several 100s or even 1000s of contributors across large projects.

Some of the basics:

1) think of git as a way to share code between developers

2) not only that, but you can manage change history and track changes over time

3) seamlessly manages most changes, enabling you and your team to view point-in-time versions

Check out the Git handbook at https://guides.github.com/introduction/git-handbook/ to get started!

To address your specific question:

- when you are ready to share your backend code, check it into your git repository and let your collaborators know that updates are available
- make sure to include instructions on how to use your backend code; do they run the server locally? is it deployed to a url? is it running in docker or kubernetes? is it authenticated, and how?
- they will "pull" your changes and start working against them; when they have updates, they should commit them to git and push to the remote repository. You can then pull down their changes and review the full frontend/backend solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these tools to make your life easier

1. Github or Bitbucket  for code collaboration
2. Postman or Postwoman for API share
3. Jira cloud or clubhouse for Issue tracking ( free for 10 users)
4. Confluence for documentation.
5. Slack for real time communication.

These are tools I am using for collaboration with others. This is just my opinion.